# Why is my CSS animation not playing?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have an image that I want to bob up and down gently, but the animation isn't easing as intended. It's meant to ease at both the top and the bottom of the path, but only eases at the bottom.* What am I missing?

```
     img {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 16px;
        margin-top: 10vh;
        height: 90vh;
        width: auto;
        animation: floaty;
        animation-direction: alternate;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        animation-timing-function: ease;
        animation-duration: 1s;
    }

    @keyframes floaty {
        0% {margin-top: 10vh;}
        to {margin-top: 14vh;}
    }
```

Comment: It works on chrome but add cross-browser compatability animation sequence as well

Comment: Works fine, tested in firefox, chrome, and safari http://codepen.io/anon/pen/peBNmv

Comment: @Michael Coker - That animation is "bouncing" at the top there, which I don't want. I want the image to look like a boat floating on the ocean.

Answer (score 2):

CSS for @keyframes is incorrectly defined. Try this:

```
@keyframes floaty {
    from {margin-top: 10vh;}
    to {margin-top: 14vh;}
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kfc1bhc2/) with the resolution

Comment: The animation is still easing incorrectly, and it worked before (0% {...} to {...}).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `%` in `keyframes`, everywhere use `%` only.

```
@keyframes floaty {
  0% {margin-top: 10vh;}
  100% {margin-top: 14vh;}
}
```

Comment: The animation is still easing incorrectly, and it worked before (0% {...} to {...}).